# Matrices that commute with all matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $Z_n$ be the set of all $n \times n$ matrices that commute with all $n \times n $ matrices.
Show that $$Z_n = \{\lambda I_n \ | \  \lambda \in \mathbb R\}$$

($I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix)

I don't know how to use $E_{ij}$ (matrix with $1$ in $(i,j)$ and $0$ elsewhere) and the elementary matrix $P_{ij}$ to prove this question. Can anyone explain it please?

Answer (score 11):

Notice that

$$E_{ij}E_{kl}=\delta_{jk}E_{il}$$
so if a matrix $$A=\sum_{1\le k,l\le n}a_{kl}E_{kl}$$
commutes with the all the matrices then it commutes with $E_{ij}$ hence we get

$$AE_{ij}=E_{ij}A\iff \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ki}E_{kj}=\sum_{l=1}^n a_{jl} E_{il}$$
so we see that

$$a_{ii}=a_{jj}=:\lambda\;\forall i,j\quad \text{and} \quad a_{ki}=0\;\forall k\ne i$$
hence $A=\lambda I_n$. Finally, it's trivial that $\lambda I_n$ does commute with all the matrices.

Comment: Thanks! There's another part that i don't know how to prove. How can I show that all diagonal entries are equal?

Comment: From the equality on the RHS of the equivalence and since $E_{ij}$ form a basis we see that only for $k=i$ and $l=j$ we may have a non zero term and that $a_{ii}=a_{jj}$ so all diagonal entries are equal.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this explanation is horrible. I'm reading over it for about the 10th time now and still can't get it, I feel like it skips way too many steps.

Comment: The answer is poorly written. Also, the whole question is closed when clearly the OP is asking for a very specific thing.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Compute $A E_{ij}$ and $E_{ij} A$. Force them to be equal.

Comment: $i,j$ should be different. I want to add it.