# Matrix multiplication: AB=BA for every B implies A is of the form cI

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies $AB = BA$ for any $n \times n$ matrix $B$, then $A$ must be of the form $cI$ where $c$ is a scalar and $I$ is the identity matrix.
I tried to use the definition of matrix multiplication, but I failed. I am wondering if I should use the inverse to solve the problem, but since now, I have no idea.

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried to use the definition of matrix multiplication, but I failed. I am wondering if I should use the inverse to solve the problem, but since now, I have no idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120202/matrices-that-commute-with-all-matrices

Comment: @GraceZ The matrices are not given to be invertible. So you can't use the inverse.

Comment: @Sahiba Arora You are right, thank you for your correction!!!

Comment: @Crostul Opps! I did not find the question. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Are you looking for something relating to a form of Schur's Lemma?

Comment: @snulty Thank you very much! But it seems that they do not have many relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take as $B$ the $n^2$ matrices $E_{ij}$, whose elements are $1$ in position $ij$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I know the solution now. I am sorry that my reputation is not enough, so I cannot change the upvote score.