# When $AB=BA$, form of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and that for all $B$ of size $n \times n$, $AB=BA$. My question is why is $A$ of the form $A=CI$ where $C$ is a scalar and $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120202/matrices-that-commute-with-all-matrices or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/a-linear-operator-commuting-with-all-such-operators-is-a-scalar-multiple-of-the

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Properties of matrix A where AB=BA?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3677177/properties-of-matrix-a-where-ab-ba)

Comment: Thank you these sources were helpful