# $A^*$ must be scalar matrix if $A$ is scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ mapping $\displaystyle *$ from $\displaystyle F_{n}$ to $\displaystyle F_{n}$ is called adjoint if

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
( A+B)^{*} =A^{*} +B^{*}\\
( AB)^{*} =B^{*} A^{*}\\
\left( A^{*}\right)^{*} =A;\\
\text{for all } A,B\in F_{n}
\end{array}$

if $\displaystyle \lambda $ is any scalar matrix in $\displaystyle F_{n}$ then prove that $\displaystyle \lambda ^{*}$ must also be a scalar matrix.

For Hermitian adjoint, I know it is true. But for general adjoint, how can I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1120202/144766) that a matrix $A \in M_n(F)$ is a scalar matrix if and only if $AB = BA$ for all $B \in M_n(F)$.

Consider the scalar matrix $\lambda I$ for some $\lambda \in F$. For any matrix $B \in M_n(F)$ we have
$$(\lambda I) B = B(\lambda I).$$
Applying $*$ on this equality gives
$$B^*(\lambda I)^*= (\lambda I)^*B^*, \quad \forall B \in M_n(F).$$
Now, $*$ is bijective since $(B^{*})^* = B$ so
$$B(\lambda I)^*= (\lambda I)^*B, \quad \forall B \in M_n(F)$$
which implies that $(\lambda I)^*$ is again a scalar matrix.