# Show that the single matrix that commutes with all invertible matrices is the scalar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that the scalar matrix $\lambda E$, with $E$ being the identity matrix and $\lambda \in K$ a constant, is the only matrix $A\in K^{n\times n}$ that commutes with all invertible matrices.

I am not sure how to tackle this question. I would appreciate if you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: What have you written down, explicitly?

Comment: Thanks! I saw that question before posting this. My problem is that I think this is a different case scenario as it is about invertible matrices: I suppose I have to show uniqueness and existence of this claim.
This is a comment in reference to another comment (that was deleted) and that suggested https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120202/matrices-that-commute-with-all-matrices

Comment: I don't know what question you’re talking about. I'm asking you to write  down some mathematical statements and think about how the invertibility condition can be used.

Comment: Sorry. At first I thought I could start by using a $2\times 2$ matrix, and say: if I assume an invertable matrix $B$, I could have the equation $B^{-1} A B = A$. $B^{-1}$ is easy to calculate, so it is straightforward. My problem is that I have to show the more general case of an invertable $n\times n$ matrix, but calculating $B^{-1}$ in this case is not as easy (so I think there should be a better approach). I also have to show that this answer is unique, so I think another approach is needed, and I don't know what should this approach be.

Comment: @Junjiro Take another approach. You have the freedom to pick any invertible matrix $A$ and use the fact that it commutes with your special matrix B (for which you want to prove that $B=\lambda E$)

Comment: Do you know the change of basis formula? It's very hard to try to guess what tools you have available when you don't post more substance.

Comment: At this point I only know the definition of a matrix in relation to two Basis and the definition of the multiplication of matrices ($ _{C_2} D_{C_1}=(d_{ij})\in K^{m\times n}$ $_{B_3} \(XY\)_{B_1}=_{B_3}X_{B_{2}} \cdot _{B_2}Y_{B_{1} $). I don't really know the change of basis formula.

Comment: At this point I only know the definition of a matrix in relation to two Basis and the definition of the multiplication of matrices ($ _{C_2} D_{C_1}=(d_{ij})\in K^{m\times n}$ $_{B_3} (XY)_{B_1}=_{B_3}X_{B_{2}} \cdot _{B_2}Y_{B_{1} }$). I don't really know the change of basis formula.

Comment: Btw, I think this is a nice question. The statement to prove is somewhat stronger than the one discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120202/matrices-that-commute-with-all-matrices That's simply because here (in this question), we know that our matrix commutes only with the invertible matrices and not with all matrices.

Comment: If $A$ and $P$, then $PAP^{-1}=A$. Choose invertible matrices $P$ and look at the result of $PAP^{-1}$ and what it implies on $A$: first consider $P=I$, except one diagonal element replaced with $k\ne0$. Repeat that on all diagonal elements and conclude that $A$ must be diagonal. Then consider $P=I$ except the $(i,j)$ element which is $k$ ($i\ne j$), and use that to prove that all diagonal elements must be equal. Done.

Comment: I took the time and wrote a detailed solution to your problem. You can check it out, see if it helps. https://fxfyfz.blogspot.com/2021/01/if-matrix-commutes-with-all-invertible.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the square matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ of size $n$ commutes with all invertible square matrices of the same size $n$.

Take this particular matrix $B = {(b_{ij})}$ where $b_{ij} = i$ when $i=j$ and $b_{ij} = 0$ if $i \ne j$.

$B$ is obviously invertible.

Use the fact that it commutes with your matrix A. So we have $AB=BA$ When we write this down in details, this easily gives us that $a_{ij} = 0$ when $i\ne j$. So all elements of $A$ which are not on the main diagonal are zeros. Now we just need to prove that all elements along the main diagonal of $A$ are equal...

I am thinking on this part myself right now. Should be some simple trick too, I just haven't figured it out yet...

**EDIT:**

Oh, here it is, the solution for the final part... Multiply now the matrix $A$ to the Vandermonde matrix $V$ (you can pick the alphas in $V$ pretty much as you wish, just take them all distinct). Vandermonde matrix is invertible (as we know from theory, from its determinant) if all alphas in $V$ are pairwise distinct.

OK... Now use the fact that $A$ commutes with $V$ and compare the first columns of the two result matrices $VA$ and $AV$. From comparing the two first columns, you easily get now that the elements along the main diagonal of $A$ are all equal (and this completes the proof). You just need to write down $VA$ and $AV$ (e.g. for $n=3$) and you will notice the pattern and why the desired statement follows.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Sorry for not answering, I am trying to understand your answer. Is A invertible? For a $2\times2$ let $A=((1,0),(0,2))$, then $A^{-1}=((2,0),(0,1))$  and $A A^{-1} = 2E \neq E$. Sorry if I am not correct. I am also reading about the Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: I just changed the notation to match your notation. You call $A$ the matrix that we know commutes with all invertible matrices. So I swapped the roles of $A$ and $B$ in my answer. So $B$ is the matrix which I constructed. $B$ is invertible as its determinant is just $n!$ and is non-zero. You have this theorem: a matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is non-zero. You didn't construct properly the matrix $B^{-1}$, that's why you get $2E$ there. The inverse matrix is actually $((1,0),(0,0.5))$

Comment: Although it's very elegant, this proof doesn't work in fields of positive characteristic for n greather or equal to the field's characteristic.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your matrices are over $\mathbb{R}$, although this approach can be modified using algebraic geometry to work over general fields.

There is a nice two-step approach: first show that a matrix that commutes with all *invertible* matrices in fact commutes with *all* matrices, and then show that the only matrices that do that are scalar multiples of the identity.

Now for step 1 there is a really nice surprising trick: use *topology*!

The key is that the set of invertible matrices is *dense* in the set of all matrices, meaning that for every matrix B, no matter how restrictive your notion of 'tiny' is, you can always find a tiny matrix $C$ such that $B + C$ is invertible. This is intuitively clear once you realize the same is true fore the determinants of $B, C$ and $B + C$.

Now given your matrix $A$ that commutes with all inverible matrices we have that the map that sends matrix $B$ to matrix $AB - BA$ is continuous and equals the zero matrix almost everywhere (on the dense subset of invertible $B$ that is) so that it follows that it equals $0$ everywhere.

Step 2 doesn't involve any surprise trick like this, so I leave that to you

Comment: I am sure the OP will appreciate the topology approach and this nice simple statement here in particular "the set of invertible matrices is dense in the set of all matrices" :)

Answer (score 1):

For any nonzero vector $u$, if $u$ and $Au$ are linearly independent, there exists some invertible matrix $B$ such that $Bu=u$ and $B(Au)=Au-u$. But then $0=(AB-BA)u=u$, which is a contradiction. Hence $u$ and $Au$ must be linearly dependent, i.e. $Au=c_uu$ for some scalar $c_u$.

This scalar $c_u$ actually does not depend on $u$. For, given any two nonzero vectors $u$ and $v$, if we pick an invertible matrix $B$ such that $Bu=v$, we obtain $0=(AB-BA)u=(c_v-c_u)v$, i.e. $c_u=c_v$. If we call this common value of all $c_u$s as $c$, we get $Au=cu$ for all nonzero vectors $u$. Hence $A=cI$.

Comment: Thanks. Why is $B(Au)=Au-u$ ?

Comment: @Junjiro There is no why. You *pick* a $B$ such that $B(Au)=Au-u$.