# Limit of matrix expression $\lim_{B \to A} {(A - B)}^{-1} (A^2 - B^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

I'm reviewing linear algebra topics after quite a few years and I'm struggling with this apparently very simple exercise.

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.
>
> a. What does it mean to say that
> $$\lim_{B \to A} {(A - B)}^{-1} (A^2 - B^2)\qquad\text{exists?}$$
>
> b. Does the limit exist when $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$?
>
> c. When $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$?

a. It means that

1. the expression is well-defined and there's a neighborhood $U$ around $A$ such that if $B \in U$ then $A - B$ is invertible, and;
2. that there exists a matrix $M$ such that, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|B - A| < \delta$ implies $|{(A - B)}^{-1} (A^2 - B^2) - M| < \varepsilon$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Frobenius norm.

b. In this case $A$ is invertible as $\det A = 1$ and since the determinant is continuous there's a neighborhood around $A$ that contains matrices $B$ so that $A - B$ has a non-zero determinant as well. This should allow us to approach $A$ with a sequence of matrices $B_n$ so that $A - B_n$ is invertible and the limit makes sense.

c. This case seems the same as the previous one. The only difference I see is that for the first matrix, $A^2 = A$, whereas in this case that isn't true. But I don't understand how that has any relevance.

Since I wasn't able to conclude whether the limit exists or not in either case, I tried to evaluate it for the general case. Let $B_n = A - n^{-1} I \to A$ as $n \to \infty$. This sequence belongs to a subset of a neighborhood of $A$ and $A - B_n$ is invertible for $n > 1$. Then we have
$${(A - B_n)}^{-1} (A^2 - B_n^2) = nI\left[A^2 - {(A - n^{-1} I)}^2\right] = 2A - n^{-1}I \to 2A$$

This result at least shows that the limit could equal $2A$. But the sequence $B_n$ is only one possible way to approach $A$. We need to show that such a result is independent of how we approach the limit point $A$. In general, we have $B = A - H$, where $|H|$ gets arbitrarily small (say $|H| < \delta$). Then:
$${(A - B)}^{-1} (A^2 - B^2) = H^{-1}\left[A^2 - {(A - H)}^2\right] = H^{-1}AH + A - H$$

Now, to prove that the limit is indeed $2A$, we need to bound the following expression with another one that depends on $\delta$ and not on $H$:

$$\begin{split}
|H^{-1}AH + A - H - 2A| &= |H^{-1}AH - A - H| \leq\\
&\leq |H^{-1}AH - A| + |H| \leq\\
&\leq |H^{-1}AH - A| + \delta
\end{split}$$

And here I don't know how to continue.

Questions:

1. What is the difference between points b and c of the exercise? I could not understand.
2. Is it possible to complete the $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof that the limit is $2A$, or is the above completely wrong?

Comment: Offhand, I would say that the difference is whether $AB=BA$ (for all $B$ near $A$). If so, there’s a very easy answer and proof.

Comment: Let  $C$   be a rank one matrix, for example  a single $1$  in position $C_{11} $  and all other entries $0$.   Next, with a small real parameter $t,$ let $B = A - t C$  so that $A-B = tC.$   This is not invertible.  In brief, there is no neighborhood $U$ around $A$ that causes the whole business to make sense

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for spotting those typos, I corrected them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that the usual definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(a)$, requiring the domain $D\subset X$ of the function $f$ to be a neighborhood in $X$ of the point $a\in X$, cannot be the one intended here, otherwise the limit in this exercise would never make sense (the subset of matrices $B$ such that $B-A$ is invertible is never a neighborhood of $A$). The intended definition here is [a more general one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_on_topological_spaces), requiring only $a$ to be [adherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point) to $D$:
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell\iff\forall V\in\mathcal V(\ell),\exists U\in\mathcal V(a),f(U\cap D\setminus\{a\})\subset V.$$
This definition can be applied here because "invertible matrices are a dense subset".

With this convention in mind, $\lim_{B \to A} {(A - B)}^{-1} (A^2 - B^2)$ exists iff $\lim_{H\to0} H^{-1} (A^2 -(A-H)^2)$ exists.

But $H^{-1}(A^2 -(A-H)^2)=H^{-1}AH+A-H,$ so the previous limits exist iff the following one does:
$$L:=\lim_{H\to0}H^{-1}AH $$
and then we have $\lim_{B \to A} {(A - B)}^{-1} (A^2 - B^2)=L+A.$

Now, the function $g(H):=H^{-1}AH$ (defined on invertible matrices) is [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) of degree $1$, i.e. $\forall t\in\Bbb R^*,g(tH)=g(H).$ Therefore, if $L$ exists then for every invertible $H$, $L=\lim_{t\to0}g(tH)=g(H)$. So, the existence of $L$ is equivalent to $g$ being constant (equal to $g(I_n)$), i.e.
$$\forall H\text{ invertible},\quad H^{-1}AH=A.$$

This last condition is [known to be equivalent to: $A$ is a scalar matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3986927), and then we have $L=A.$

Comment: Thanks Anne, I have two questions on the above:

1. the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limits I know requires the limit expression to be defined on a neighborhood of the limit point. But from the above, it seems we're fine if we just consider the particular subset of invertible matrices around the limit point. Is that fine because invertible matrices are a dense subset?

2. What does "homogeneity" refers to in your sentence "By homogeneity, ..."? I looked it up but there are so many different definitions.

Comment: Ah, now I understand, the domain of the limit expression includes only those matrices $B$ such that $A - B$ is invertible. So we're considering a neighborhood in the domain, which is not the same as a neighborhood in the space of $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: Nearly but not exactly, because $A$ itself does not belong to the domain $D=\{B\in M_n\mid A-B\in GL_n\}$, so formally, speaking of "a neighborhood [of $A$] in the domain" does not really make sense. I don't think we can formulate it more simply than $U\cap D\setminus\{A\}$ where $U$ is a neighborhood of $A$ in $M_n.$

Answer (score 2):

First off, notice that no matrix $A$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $A - B$ is invertible for all $B \subset U$. Simply take $B = A - C$ where $C$ is any non-invertible matrix with an arbitrarily small norm. So to define the limit, one must consider only those $B$ such that $A - B$ is invertible.

Regarding your approach, you didn't notice that $H^{-1}AH = A$ when $A$ is the identity, so that the limit is always $2A$. You can also obatain the limit quickly in the following way: If $A$ is the identity, then $AB = BA$ for all matrices $B$. Hence, $A^2 - B^2 = (A - B)(A + B)$. But if $A - B$ is invertible then the expression in the limit reduces to $A + B$. Letting $B$ tend to $A$, we see that the limit is $2A$.

The same trick does not work in (c), because \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix} does not commute with all matrices. You would actually get different limits depending on how you approached $A$. For example, taking $B = (1 + t)A$ and letting $t$ tend to $0$, we get the limit $2A$. However, if you let $B$ equal \begin{bmatrix}t & 1\\1 & 2t\end{bmatrix} then (if I have not made a mistake) after some computation you obtain \begin{bmatrix}0 & 3\\\frac{3}{2} & 0\end{bmatrix} in the limit as $t \to 0$.