# Proving that a matrix that commutes with all other matrices is a multiple of the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm trying to prove that if there is $Z \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $[X, Z] = 0$ for all $X \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, then $Z=cI$ for some complex number $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

I first noted that if $Z$ fulfills this requirement, then $Z + aI$ also does. This seems like the start of my proof. Now I'm not sure where to go from here. I know that I need to show that if $Z$ isn't a multiple of $I$, then it can't commute with every matrix. I'm not sure how/if I should leverage the first stated fact to do this. Can I get a hint?

Comment: Your problem statement seems garbled in that $X$ should be a matrix, not a complex number (where you wrote $X\in \mathbb C$).  In any case if I understand the problem you meant to ask, this has been asked before.  See [matrices that commute with all matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120202/matrices-that-commute-with-all-matrices)

Comment: Hint: Let $A_{ij}$ be a matrix with $1$ in entry $(i,j)$ and $0$ elsewhere

Comment: Since this is tagged Representation Theory I'll point out that with a little cleverness you can do this directly via Schur's Lemma (i.e. your statement implies $Z$ commutes with a dim n irreducible representation of a finite group)

Comment: @user8675309 How can I use the fact that Z commutes to show that it makes an isomorphism from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to itself? Do we construct some new mapping that inputs an element from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to the commutator with $Z$ and then show that the result always being zero means we have some sort of irreducible representation?

Comment: *'How can I use the fact that Z commutes to show that it makes an isomorphism from* $_n$(ℂ) to itself?" You can't.  This is not a group and $Z$ need not be invertible. E.g. $Z=\mathbf 0$ works and a priori you don't know there isn't some satisfying $Z$ with $0\lt \text{rank}\big(Z\big) \lt n$.  The point is, with scalars over $\mathbb C$ there is always an irreducible $n$ dimensional (matrix) representation of a finite group.  Why is this true?  (Hint: consider $S_d$ the permutation group for operating on a set with $d$ elements).  $Z$ commutes with said rep so you can apply Schur's Lemma.